# How can I define a buffer-local variable in a FileType autocommand using vim9script?

Tags: vim9script

I am trying to define a buffer variable based on the `FileType` as it follows:

```
vim9script

def g:MyComment(comment_symbol: string)
    # Do something
enddef

augroup commenting_blocks_of_code
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,java.      b:comment_symbol = '//'
    autocmd FileType sh,vim,python    b:comment_symbol = '#'
    autocmd FileType tex              b:comment_symbol = '%'
augroup END
```

So far, I tested in my `.vimrc`, in a `.c` and in a `.tex` file and it works but it won't work on `.py` files as I get `error E121: undefined variable b:comment_symbol`

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Not on vim 9 but have you tried declaring the variable first like `var b:comment_symbol = '//'`

Comment: Yes. Then it complains about E1016: Cannot declare a buffer variable error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` for variable assignments. (also, there's an extra dot after java).

```
augroup commenting_blocks_of_code
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,java       let b:comment_symbol = '//'
    autocmd FileType sh,vim,python    let b:comment_symbol = '#'
    autocmd FileType tex              let b:comment_symbol = '%'
augroup END
```

Also the standard way to define a vimscript function is using `function` instead of `def`, see `:h def` and `:h E124`

```
function g:MyComment()
  "...
endfunction
```

So finally you may be desiring this piece of code:

```
augroup commenting_blocks_of_code
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,java       let b:comment_symbol = '//'
    autocmd FileType sh,vim,python    let b:comment_symbol = '#'
    autocmd FileType tex              let b:comment_symbol = '%'
augroup END
" map Ctrl-Slash to creating a comment section
" NOTE WE'RE USING <C-_> for Ctrl-Slash
vnoremap <silent> <C-_> :s@^@\=b:comment_symbol<CR>
```

Comment: I am using vim9script.

Comment: @Barzi2001 Sorry but I cant help; I'm still on 8

Comment: Then you should add `vim9script` at the top of your sample, just like at the top of your script.

Comment: @romainl fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I erroneously changed `python` with `py`, i.e. I had the following in my script:

```
autocmd FileType sh,vim,py        b:comment_symbol = '#'
```

using `py` as `FileType` for python won't work, but one has to use `python` instead:

```
autocmd FileType sh,vim,python        b:comment_symbol = '#'
```

Comment: And yet the sample in your question spells `python` correctly.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But you know, when the time spent becomes considerably high you get frustrated and you start to mess up stupidly. I have made the attempt to  replace python with py but I forgot to revert the change locally. Things happen. in-fact I was thinking to delete the post in first place, but then I thought that some people may confuse file extension and  file type and make my same mistake.